Angular SSR - Render HTML without HTML and BODY tags
I need to create an Angular SSR application that renders a server-side page containing only the component, without the HEAD, HTML, and BODY tags. Currently, if we try to change the post-rendering to achieve this, we receive a hydration error.
From the documentation, it's not clear how to render a component without these tags.
The problem is that, if we import the component into another page through a second server-side rendering, the browser automatically removes the HTML and BODY tags, causing the error.
Since I would like to leverage hydration, I want to understand if there is an intelligent way to potentially render the component.
I have seen that other frameworks, such as Astro.build, use a method called Astro Island, which is exactly what I want to achieve.
Any ideas?
